# Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got this "500 Internal Server Error - LogicException: **Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information**".

Here is my controller's action definition:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/gatherplayer/{player_name}/{gather_id}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Player $player, Gather $gather)
{
  // ...
}
```

And it doesn't work, probably because Doctrine 2 can not "guess"... So how do I make Doctrine 2 guess, and well?

Comment: You should take a look at [@ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) annotation.

Comment: ParamConverter from SensioFrameworkExtraBundle are replaced by value resolver from symfony itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77014603/11350193

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/**
 * @Route("/gatherplayer/{name}/{id}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Player $player, Gather $gather)
```

I didn't find any help in paramconverter's (poor?) documentation, since it doesn't describe how it works, how it guesses with more than one parameters and stuff. Plus I'm not sure it's needed since what I just wrote works properly.

My mystake was not to use the name of my attributs so doctrine couldn't guess right. I changed  {player_name} to {name} and {gather_id} to {id}.

Then I changed the names of my id in their entities from "id" to "id_gather" and "id_player" so I'm now able to do that :

```
/**
 * @Route("/gatherplayer/{id_player}/{id_gather}")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Player $player, Gather $gather)
```

which is a lot more effective than

```
 * @Route("/gatherplayer/{id}/{id}")
```

Now I'm wondering how I can make this work

```
 /**
  * @Route("/gatherplayer/{player}/{gather}")
  * @Template()
  */
 public function deleteAction(Gather_Player $gather_player)
```

Answer (score 38):

The Doctrine doesn't know how to use request parameters in order to query  entities specified in the function's signature.

You will need to help it by specifying some mapping information:

```php
/**
  * @Route("/gatherplayer/{player_name}/{gather_id}")
  *
  * @ParamConverter("player", options={"mapping": {"player_name" : "name"}})
  * @ParamConverter("gather", options={"mapping": {"gather_id"   : "id"}})
  *
  * @Template()
  */
public function createAction(Player $player, Gather $gather)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/gatherplayer/{player_name}/{gather_id}")
 * @ParamConverter("player", class="YourBundle:Player")
 * @ParamConverter("gather", class="YourBundle:Gather")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Player $player, Gather $gather)
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameters on the signature of the @Route annotation must match the entities fields, so that Doctrine makes automatically the convertion.

Otherwise you need to do the convertion manually by using the annotation @ParamConverter as it's mentionned on the other responses.

Answer (score 0):

@1ed is right, you should define a @paramConverter in order to get a Player instance or a Gather instance.

Comment: How can I use @paramConverter in a YAML config file?

Comment: @paramConverter is implemented by SensioFrameworkExtraBundle. I don't think that the bundle expose this functionality via yml o xml config file, I think that the only way is using annotation.

Answer (score 0):

As of symfony 6.2, SensioFrameworkExtraBundle is deprecated. Features such as annotation routing, param convertion are now integrated in [Symfony](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes) directly.

> Note that ParamConverter are now called ValueResolver

**You need to be in Symfony > 6.2, PHP >= 8.1 and DoctrineBundle >= 2.7.1**

It is now easy to map an ID to an entity :

```
#[Route('/post/{id}')]
public function show(Post $post): Response
{
    //  $post is a Post entity
}
```

This behavior is activated by default and can be disabled with `doctrine.orm.controller_resolver.auto_mapping` to false.

If you are fetching your object differently, by another property for example, instead of using the `ParamConverter` from SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, you can now use the `#[MapEntity]` php attribute.

Example from the link posted above replacing a ParamConverter with MapEntity when using a slug to find your entity:

```
#[ParamConverter('post', options: ['mapping' => ['postSlug' => 'slug']])]
public function addComment(Request $request, Post $post): Response
```

Turn into:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Attribute\MapEntity;
public function addComment(
    Request $request,
    #[MapEntity(mapping: ['postSlug' => 'slug'])] Post $post
): Response
```

MapEntity has plenty other [options](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#mapentity-options) that can be useful.

See the documentation about [Automatically Fetching Objects (EntityValueResolver)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#doctrine-entity-value-resolver)