# Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3
- `CalendarEntity` can be parent of `ChocolateEntity`
- `BoxEntity` is parent `WrapperEntity`
- `WrapperEntity` can be parent of `ChocolateEntity` and is always a child of `BoxEntity`
- `ChocolateEntity` can only be child of either `CalendarEntity` or `WrapperEntity`

[image: Diagram]

**[PROBLEM]**

When I try to navigate to `chocolate/show` or `chocolate/edit` route from either `CalendarEntity` or `BoxEntity` , I get this message:

> Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information

`chocolate/index` and `chocolate/new` routes are working fine.
And untill I came to add code in controller for `CalendarEntity`, every routes were working fine.

Checking dev.log file gave me this:

```
// Route: /calendar/{idCalendar}/chocolate/{idChocolate}/show
request.INFO: Matched route "calendar_chocolate_show". {"route":"calendar_chocolate_show","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\ChocolateController::showAction","idCalendar":"1","idChocolate":"3","_route":"calendar_chocolate_show"},"request_uri":"http://sphere.gdn/app_dev.php/calendar/1/chocolate/3/show","method":"GET"} []

// Route: /box/{idBox}/wrapper/{idWrapper}/chocolate/{idChocolate}/show
request.INFO: Matched route "wrapper_chocolate_show". {"route":"wrapper_chocolate_show","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\\Controller\\ChocolateController::showAction","idBox":"1","idWrapper":"1","idChocolate":"1","_route":"wrapper_chocolate_show"},"request_uri":"http://sphere.gdn/app_dev.php/box/1/wrapper/1/chocolate/1/show","method":"GET"} []
```

As I see it, Symfony have all needed paramters for each request, and no extra parameter.
I can't ind out how to fix this problem.

**[FILES]**

*ENTITIES :*

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Calendar.php</kbd>**

```
class Calendar {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idCalendar;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nameCalendar;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Chocolate", mappedBy="calendar")
     */
    private $chocolate;
}
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Box.php</kbd>**

```
class Box {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idBox;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nameBox;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Wrapper", mappedBy="box")
     */
    private $wrapper;
}
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Wrapper.php</kbd>**

```
class Wrapper {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idWrapper;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nameWrapper;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Box", inversedBy="wrapper")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=false)
     */
    private $box;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Chocolate", mappedBy="wrapper")
     */
    private $chocolate;
}
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Entity/Chocolate.php</kbd>**

```
class Chocolate {
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $idChocolate;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nameChocolate;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Calendar", inversedBy="chocolate")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     */
    private $calendar;
    /**
     * @var
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Wrapper", inversedBy="chocolate")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     */
    private $wrapper;
}
```

*ROUTINGS :*

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Resources/config/calendar.yml</kbd>**

```
# Calendar
calendar_show:
    path:     /calendar/{idCalendar}/show/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Calendar:show" }
    methods:  GET

calendar_edit:
    path:     /calendar/{idCalendar}/edit/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Calendar:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

# Chocolate
calendar_chocolate:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Resources/config/box.yml</kbd>**

```
#Box
box_show:
    path:     /box/{idBox}/show/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Box:show" }
    methods:  GET

box_edit:
    path:     /box/{idBox}/edit/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Box:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

# Wrapper
box_wrapper:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/wrapper.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Resources/config/wrapper.yml</kbd>**

```
# Wrapper
wrapper_show:
    path:     /box/{idBox}/wrapper/{idWrapper}/show/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Wrapper:show" }
    methods:  GET

wrapper_edit:
    path:     /box/{idBox}/wrapper/{idWrapper}/edit/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Wrapper:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

# Chocolate
wrapper_chocolate:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml</kbd>**

```
# Calendar Chocolate
calendar_chocolate_show:
    path:     /calendar/{idCalendar}/chocolate/{idChocolate}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Chocolate:show" }
    methods:  GET

calendar_chocolate_edit:
    path:     /calendar/{idCalendar}/chocolate/{idChocolate}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Chocolate:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

# Box Chocolate
wrapper_chocolate_show:
    path:     /box/{idBox}/wrapper/{idWrapper}/chocolate/{idChocolate}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Chocolate:show" }
    methods:  GET

wrapper_chocolate_edit:
    path:     /box/{idBox}/wrapper/{idWrapper}/chocolate/{idChocolate}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Chocolate:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]
```

*CONTROLLERS :*

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Controller/CalendarController.php</kbd>**

```
class CalendarController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Finds and displays a Calendar entity.
     *
     * @param Calendar $calendar
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function showAction(Calendar $calendar) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($calendar);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:calendar:show.html.twig', array(
            'calendar'=>$calendar,
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Calendar entity.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Calendar $calendar
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Calendar $calendar) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($calendar);
        $editForm=$this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\CalendarType', $calendar);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getManager();
            $em->persist($calendar);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('calendar_edit', array('idCalendar'=>$calendar->getIdCalendar()));
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:calendar:edit.html.twig', array(
            'calendar'=>$calendar,
            'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Controller/BoxController.php</kbd>**

```
class BoxController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Finds and displays a Box entity.
     *
     * @param Box $box
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function showAction(Box $box) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($box);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:box:show.html.twig', array(
            'box'=>$box,
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Box entity.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Box $box
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Box $box) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($box);
        $editForm=$this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\BoxType', $box);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getManager();
            $em->persist($box);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('box_edit', array('idBox'=>$box->getIdBox()));
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:box:edit.html.twig', array(
            'box'=>$box,
            'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Controller/WrapperController.php</kbd>**

```
class WrapperController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Finds and displays a Wrapper entity.
     *
     * @param Box $box
     * @param Wrapper $wrapper
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function showAction(Box $box, Wrapper $wrapper) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($box, $wrapper);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:wrapper:show.html.twig', array(
            'box'=>$box,
            'wrapper'=>$wrapper,
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Wrapper entity.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Box $box
     * @param Wrapper $wrapper
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Box $box, Wrapper $wrapper) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($box, $wrapper);
        $editForm=$this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\WrapperType', $wrapper);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getManager();
            $em->persist($wrapper);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirectToRoute('wrapper_edit', array(
                'idBox'=>$box->getIdBox(),
                'idWrapper'=>$wrapper->getIdWrapper()
            ));
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:wrapper:edit.html.twig', array(
            'box'=>$box,
            'wrapper'=>$wrapper,
            'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Controller/ChocolateController.php</kbd>**

```
class ChocolateController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Finds and displays a Chocolate entity.
     *
     * @param Calendar $calendar
     * @param Box $box
     * @param Wrapper $wrapper
     * @param Chocolate $chocolate
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function showAction(Calendar $calendar=null, Box $box=null, Wrapper $wrapper=null, Chocolate $chocolate) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($calendar, $box, $wrapper, $chocolate);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:chocolate:show.html.twig', array(
            'calendar'=>$calendar,
            'box'=>$box,
            'wrapper'=>$wrapper,
            'chocolate'=>$chocolate,
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Chocolate entity.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Calendar $calendar
     * @param Box $box
     * @param Wrapper $wrapper
     * @param Chocolate $chocolate
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Calendar $calendar=null, Box $box=null, Wrapper $wrapper=null, Chocolate $chocolate) {
        $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($calendar, $box, $wrapper, $chocolate);
        $editForm=$this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ChocolateType', $chocolate);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $em=$this->getDoctrine()
                     ->getManager();
            $em->persist($chocolate);
            $em->flush();
            if($box) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('wrapper_box_chocolate_edit', array(
                    'idBox'=>$box->getIdBox(),
                    'idWrapper'=>$wrapper->getIdWrapper(),
                    'idChocolate'=>$chocolate->getIdChocolate()
                ));
            } else {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('calendar_chocolate_edit', array(
                    'idCalendar'=>$calendar->getIdCalendar(),
                    'idWrapper'=>$wrapper->getIdWrapper(),
                    'idChocolate'=>$chocolate->getIdChocolate()
                ));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:chocolate:edit.html.twig', array(
            'calendar'=>$calendar,
            'box'=>$box,
            'wrapper'=>$wrapper,
            'chocolate'=>$chocolate,
            'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726452/unable-to-guess-how-to-get-a-doctrine-instance-from-the-request-information)

Comment: Checked this answer already, but his case and mine seems differents, and his explanations are sloppy... Couldn't get real hints on the problem.

Comment: have you used @ParamConverter ?

Comment: Yeah, like "suggested" in the linked topic. But just like I told Alvin, it did nothing. And symfony doc have no exemple on how to use it when multiple entities are using a common entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As every entities are related, you don't need to pass extra parameter to your `showAction()` or `editAction()`.

Taking back your code, `showAction()` would become this:

```
public function showAction(Chocolate $chocolate) {
    $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($video);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:chocolate:show.html.twig', array(
        'chocolate'=>$chocolate,
        'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

And your `editAction()` would become this:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Chocolate $chocolate) {
    $deleteForm=$this->createDeleteForm($chocolate);
    $editForm=$this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ChocolateType', $chocolate);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()
                 ->getManager();
        $em->persist($chocolate);
        $em->flush();
        if($chocolate->getWrapper() !== null) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('wrapper_chocolate_edit', 

        array(
            'idBox'=>$chocolate->getWrapper()->getBox()->getIdBox(),
            'idWrapper'=>$chocolate->getWrapper()->getIdWrapper(),
            'idChocolate'=>$chocolate->getIdChocolate()
        ));
    } else {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('calendar_chocolate_edit',
            array(
                'idCalendar'=>$chocolate->getCalendar()->getIdCalendar(),
                'idChocolate'=>$chocolate->getIdChocolate()
                ));
            }
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Dashboard/chocolate:edit.html.twig', array(
            'chocolate'=>$chocolate,
            'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form'=>$deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Every informations are in the `ChocolateEntity`, you just need to get the parent each time, and then the parameter needed.

As you did things, only `showAction()` and `newAction()` will need to have parameters, that is because, in both case, you don't return a specific `ChocolateEntity`

```
public function indexAction(Calendar $calendar=null, Wrapper $wrapper=null)
public function newAction(Request $request, Calendar $calendar=null, Wrapper $wrapper=null)
```

And like the `editAction()` you can get the parents without passing them.

Also note that your twig will change a bit.
As exemple, when you display an entity (`showAction()`), the link "Back to the list" will change based on the route, it will then give something like this:

```
{% if chocolate.wrapper is not null %}
    <a href="{{ path('wrapper_chocolate_list', { 'idBox': chocolate.wrapper.box.idBox, 'idWrapper': chocolate.wrapper.idWrapper }) }}">Back to the list</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('calendar_chocolate_list', { 'idCalendar': chocolate.calendar.idCalendar }) }}">Back to the list</a>
{% endif %}
```

Doing so, will hint Symfony to get the parents data even if you only pass the `ChocolateEntity` as argument. It will be the same for other twig files.

Hope it will help you.

This topic was yummy, going to get some chocolates myself.

Comment: Solved my problem indeed! Applied it all over my project, while I was at it, thanks for the detailled reply!

Answer (score 0):

So Preciel, in the ChocolateController try:

```
/**
 * Finds and displays a Chocolate entity.
 *
 * @param Calendar $calendar
 * @param Box $box
 * @param Wrapper $wrapper
 * @param Chocolate $chocolate
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 *
 *  @ParamConverter("calendar", class="AppBundle:Calendar")
 *  @ParamConverter("chocolate", class="AppBundle:Chocolate")
 */
public function showAction(Calendar $calendar=null, Box $box=null, Wrapper $wrapper=null, Chocolate $chocolate) {
...
```

I think @Vamsi is correct.

Comment: I tried such a simple syntax yes, even extented it to the two other entities, but didn't work. :(

Comment: What didn't work? Can you show the the log of what you get with this route: `http://sphere.gdn/app_dev.php/calendar/1/chocolate/3/show`

Comment: Hi there Preciel. I wasn't planning on spending too much time on this. Most so users are very busy, that's why we like good (well worded) questions. Can you use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) to post the logs?

Comment: Oh I didn't meant it that way. Just that, as you can guess, everything was renamed. So I thought that being able to access my site on the dev side would help you better, is all. Here the lines I get when I access the path. pastebin.com/y9LYNj8m