# Package sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned

Tags: php, symfony, package

when I wanted to upgrade symfony from 6.1 to 6.2, I saw this message:

```
Package sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use Symfony instead.
```

I want to know how to do it because I deleted the package and I have routes that no longer work.

How to do ? thank you

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample error message or at least a route that is no longer working?  I ask because the routing stuff has been deprecated since 5.2 so it's difficult to accept that you would still have them in a working 6.1 application.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using annotations or attributes for routes are now fully integrated in the Symfony namespace.

You are probably using `use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;` in your controllers.

Use `Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route` instead.

You can then remove the FrameworkExtraBundle with fully working routes.

```
composer remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```

You may be using this bundle for more annotations such as `IsGranted` or `ParamConverter`, there are also available in [symfony 6 (list of all attributes)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/attributes.html).

[Example with the new #[MapEntity] to replace ParamConverter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77014603/11350193)

Comment: I deleted sensio again and obviously I couldn't have the problem (even though I didn't do anything) I had a road autowrite problem. I just made the reason for my vote use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security as CoreSecurity; -> use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security; thank you!

Comment: in fact I also had this following pb: ``  Failed to remove file "public/bundles\fosckeditor\bender-runner.config.json": unlink(public/bundles\fosckeditor\bender-runner.config.json): Resource temporaril`` and it was on the roads that had ckeditor that I had the pb of autowrited. I deleted and reinstalled ckeditor and everything is fine. Thank you

Comment: What if I'm using @ParamConverter annotation? What is the replacement now? I can't find anything about it in current docs...

Comment: @jbator https://www.codinghood.de/news/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes/#:~:text=However%2C%20if%20you%20use%20%23%5BParamConverter%5D%2C%20you%E2%80%99ll%20need%20to%20make%20some%20changes%20to%0Aturn%20it%20into%20the%20new%20%23%5BMapEntity%5D%20attribute.

Comment: @jbator here's a more official link regarding ParamConverter change to MapEntity annotation: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes

Comment: Note that custom param converters are now called "value resolvers", doc: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html

Comment: What is the replacement for Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted ?

Comment: @mattheo IsGranted is available as a new php attributes https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/attributes.html (I edited my answer to speak about IsGranted & ParamConverter

Answer (score 2):

To replace `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted` use  #[IsGranted()] - attribute was introduced in Symfony 6.2.

Answer (score 1):

Default Symfony 6.2 --webapp including sensio/framework-extra-bundle.
So you will have this warning by default.

Feel free to remove it:

```
composer remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle
```