# How to solve symfony 5.4 tutorial autowiring problem?

Tags: php, symfony

I am following the symfony fast-track tutorial.
Now I am stuck on Building the User Interface/Creating the Page for a Conference.
When opening the page: https://127.0.0.1:8000/conference/1 there comes this error:

```
Cannot autowire argument $conference of "App\Controller\ConferenceController::show()": it references class "App\Entity\Conference" but no such service exists.
```

The controller looks like this:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Conference;
use App\Repository\CommentRepository;
use App\Repository\ConferenceRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Twig\Environment;
    
class ConferenceController extends AbstractController
{

#[Route('/conference/{id}', name: 'conference')]
public function show(Environment $twig, Conference $conference, CommentRepository $commentRepository): Response
{
    return new Response($twig->render('conference/show.html.twig', [
        'conference' => $conference,
        'comments' => $commentRepository->findBy(['conference' => $conference], ['createdAt' => 'DESC']),
    ]));
}
```

I read about autowireing that it should be set up automatically.

The services.yml looks like this:

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
    autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/'
    exclude:
        - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
        - '../src/Entity/'
        - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

I wonder what needs to be adjusted.
Any ideas?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle installed to get this

Comment: @ChrisHaas According to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74685374/package-sensio-framework-extra-bundle-is-abandoned) that's  functionality that is included in Symfony from 5.2 onwards, `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` is abandoned.

Comment: @cafce25, as to the abandonment part, the bundle was migrated into core in 6.2: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-2-built-in-cache-security-template-and-doctrine-attributes

Comment: The problem is an absence of SensioFrameworkExtraBundle, but when I install it I get a warning "Package sensio/framework-extra-bundle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use Symfony instead." But all the things work just like in the Book.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` did not work for me, additionaly it's abandoned. The thing that did work for me was adding `Conference` to the `config/services.yml` file like [hareth py](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14763977/hareth-py) suggests in their deleted answer.

> ```yaml
> services:
>     # ...
>
>     App\Entity\Conference:
>         autowire: true
> ```

I do believe this is a workaround, but at least it works.

---

<sup><sup>I'll leave this here for future viewers unless hareth decides to undelete their answer, feel free to ping me.</sup></sup>

Comment: this kind of worked for me, in a way that it removed the fatal error, but the auto-fetching of the `conference` does not work, having only an empty `Conference` object. 
So, I ended up by passing `id` from the path and fetching the conference by this id using a repository:
...
`public function show(int $id, Environment $twig, ConferenceRepository $conferenceRepository, CommentRepository $commentRepository): Response`
    
{
        $conference = $conferenceRepository->find($id);
...