# Replacing @ParamConverter with #[MapEntity]: You have requested a non-existent resolver EntityValueResolver

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am currently refactoring a symfony 6.3 app to remove `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` since its deprecated since symfony 6.2.

While refactoring the `@ParamConverter` annotation to use the symfony equivalent `#[MapEntity]` attribute I get the following error in the functional test for that route:

```
<!-- Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter &quot;externalAttachment&quot;. (500 Internal Server Error) -->
```

The symptoms are similar to [Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726452/unable-to-guess-how-to-get-a-doctrine-instance-from-the-request-information), but I want to use the `#[MapEntity]` attribute

Here is the diff of what I refactored:

```
 class CopyExternalAttachmentAction extends AbstractController
 {
      #[Route(path: '/app/external_attachment/{advertisementId}/{attachmentId}/copy', name: 'external_attachment_copy', requirements: ['advertisementId' => '\d+', 'attachmentId' => '\d+'], options: ['expose' => true], methods: ['GET'])]
-     #[Entity('attachment', expr: 'repository.findValidAttachment(advertisementId, attachmentId)')]
-     public function __invoke(ExternalAttachment $attachment): Response
+     public function __invoke(
+         #[MapEntity(expr: 'repository.findValidAttachment(advertisementId, attachmentId)')]
+         ExternalAttachment $externalAttachment
+     ): Response
 ...
```

When I now `composer remove sensio/framework-extra-bundle`, the error changes to

```
<!-- You have requested a non-existent resolver &quot;Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver&quot;. Did you mean one of these: &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\BackedEnumValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\DateTimeValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\DefaultValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\QueryParameterValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\RequestAttributeValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\RequestPayloadValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\RequestValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\ServiceValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\SessionValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver\VariadicValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Controller\SecurityTokenValueResolver&quot;, &quot;Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Controller\UserValueResolver&quot;, &quot;argument_resolver.not_tagged_controller&quot;, &quot;doctrine.orm.entity_value_resolver&quot;, &quot;sonata.admin.argument_resolver.admin&quot;, &quot;sonata.admin.argument_resolver.proxy_query&quot;? (500 Internal Server Error) -->
```

which seems odd to me, because im not using the ParamConverter anymore.

**My question now is: Why cant symfony/doctrine find the `EntityValueResolver` in this case?**

## Further Details

composer.json:

```
...
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "babdev/pagerfanta-bundle": "^4.2",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "*",
        "dragonmantank/cron-expression": "^3.3",
        "enqueue/amqp-lib": "^0.10.19",
        "enqueue/enqueue-bundle": "^0.10.8",
        "enqueue/job-queue": "^0.10.8",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^3.3",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^3.0",
        "geocoder-php/free-geoip-provider": "^4.3",
        "geocoder-php/google-maps-provider": "^4.5",
        "geocoder-php/nominatim-provider": "^5.4",
        "graylog2/gelf-php": "^2.0",
        "happyr/doctrine-specification": "^2.0",
        "happyr/message-serializer": "^0.5.1",
        "igorw/get-in": "~1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.7",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "^2.0",
        "knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle": "^2.11",
        "laminas/laminas-soap": "^2.8",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "^5.0",
        "league/flysystem": "^3.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.0",
        "league/flysystem-bundle": "^3.0",
        "league/flysystem-ftp": "^3.0",
        "league/flysystem-memory": "^3.0",
        "league/flysystem-sftp-v3": "^3.15",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "^2.2",
        "liip/monitor-bundle": "^2.16",
        "mikey179/vfsstream": "^1.6",
        "myclabs/deep-copy": "^1.10",
        "myclabs/php-enum": "^1.8",
        "nelmio/security-bundle": "^3.0",
        "nikic/iter": "^2.0",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.3",
        "ocramius/doctrine-batch-utils": "*",
        "pagerfanta/doctrine-orm-adapter": "^4.2",
        "pagerfanta/twig": "^4.2",
        "php-http/cache-plugin": "^1.7",
        "php-http/discovery": "^1.15",
        "php-http/httplug-bundle": "^1.18",
        "phpoption/phpoption": "^1.7",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^3",
        "portphp/csv": "^2.0",
        "portphp/dbal": "^1.0@dev",
        "portphp/doctrine": "^1.1",
        "portphp/portphp": "^1.4",
        "portphp/steps": "^1.3",
        "portphp/symfony-console": "^1.0",
        "roave/better-reflection": "^6.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.1",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/entity-audit-bundle": "1.9.*",
        "sroze/messenger-enqueue-transport": "^0.6.0",
        "stevenmaguire/oauth2-keycloak": "^4.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.6",
        "sylius-labs/association-hydrator": "^1.1",
        "sylius/grid-bundle": "^1.8",
        "symfony/amqp-messenger": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.3.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.12",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/http-client": "*",
        "symfony/lock": "*",
        "symfony/mailer": "*",
        "symfony/messenger": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-messageformatter": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/property-info": "*",
        "symfony/runtime": "*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/validator": "*",
        "symfony/web-link": "*",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/workflow": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "*",
        "twig/cssinliner-extra": "^3.0",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/inky-extra": "^3.0",
        "twig/intl-extra": "^3.2",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^2.1",
        "webmozart/assert": "^1.9",
        "willdurand/geocoder-bundle": "^5.11",
        "willdurand/js-translation-bundle": "^5.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": true,
            "require": "6.3.*"
        }
    }
...
```

`composer info` all packages starting with `doctrine/`

```
doctrine/annotations                          1.14.3  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                                2.2.0   PHP Doctrine Cache library is a popular cache implementation that su...
doctrine/collections                          1.8.0   PHP Doctrine Collections library that adds additional functionality ...
doctrine/common                               3.4.3   PHP Doctrine Common project is a library that provides additional fu...
doctrine/data-fixtures                        1.6.7   Data Fixtures for all Doctrine Object Managers
doctrine/dbal                                 2.13.9  Powerful PHP database abstraction layer (DBAL) with many features fo...
doctrine/deprecations                         v0.5.3  A small layer on top of trigger_error(E_USER_DEPRECATED) or PSR-3 lo...
doctrine/doctrine-bundle                      2.7.2   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle             3.4.4   Symfony DoctrineFixturesBundle
doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle           3.2.4   Symfony DoctrineMigrationsBundle
doctrine/event-manager                        1.2.0   The Doctrine Event Manager is a simple PHP event system that was bui...
doctrine/inflector                            2.0.8   PHP Doctrine Inflector is a small library that can perform string ma...
doctrine/instantiator                         1.5.0   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without i...
doctrine/lexer                                1.2.3   PHP Doctrine Lexer parser library that can be used in Top-Down, Recu...
doctrine/migrations                           3.4.2   PHP Doctrine Migrations project offer additional functionality on to...
doctrine/orm                                  2.14.3  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
doctrine/persistence                          3.2.0   The Doctrine Persistence project is a set of shared interfaces and f...
doctrine/sql-formatter                        1.1.3   a PHP SQL highlighting library
```

Comment: Are you importing `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Attribute\MapEntity;` ?

Comment: Also what is your doctrine exact version ? (and symfony, but if you are in 6.3 it should be fine).

Comment: Hi @DylanKAS, yes `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Attribute\MapEntity` is being imported. Regarding the doctrine version, I have updated my question.

Comment: Symfony packages are on 6.3 as managed using symfony/flex

Answer (score 2):

You need doctrine-bundle 2.9.0 at least